# How to calculate signatures numerically in rough path theory.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, stochastic-differential-equations, rough-path-theory

The question is related to the 
link:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_path#Signature I search the internet looking for tutorial on how to calculate the signature sequence, but could not find a clear document. The first term is one the second term seems to be $X_t−X_s$ but after the 2nd term how can I calculate the other integral? Consider a simplest curve, I have a set of numbers which form a line and sorted properly. This is a function also a very simple curve. For such curve can we have a signature? How to calculate the terms?  Any hint or reference would be helpful.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by calculate numerically? Can you clarify?

Comment: @ZacharySelk thanks, I changed it. the tensor product and the integral how to evaluate it?

Comment: In a rough path, you don't calculate it, you postulate it

Comment: @ZacharySelk so ones assumed the values of the integrals?

Comment: Yes, that is the entire point of rough paths.

Comment: @ZacharySelk In that case there must be a systematic way how to assume?

Comment: There is no systematic way to postulate the values of those integral. It depends on your path. Furthermore, for every path that has a rough path lift there are infinitely many rough path lifts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rough path **postulates** the iterated integrals. So given a regular path, you must **postulate** or **define** (part of) the signature to make it into a rough path.

These are not unique! This is the point of rough path theory. Given a second order rough path, $(X_{st},\Bbb X_{st})$ with $X\in C^\alpha$ for $\alpha\in (1/3,1/2]$ you can define another rough path $(X_{st},\Bbb X_{st}+F_t-F_s)$ where $F$ is a $2\alpha$ Hoelder function.

These both have the same underlying path. However in the first case we have

$$\int_{s<s_1<s_2<t}dX_{s_1}\otimes dX_{s_2}=\Bbb X_{st}$$

And in the second case:

$$\int_{s<s_1<s_2<t}dX_{s_1}\otimes dX_{s_2}=\Bbb X_{st}+F_t-F_s$$

Both of these have the same underlying path but you have **different** iterated integrals.

> The entire point of rough path theory is that you **CANNOT CALCULATE ITERATED INTEGRALS FROM** $X_t$ **ALONE**.

In rough paths, you postulate those values, and there are infinitely many ways to do this.

However from Lyons Victoir extension theorem, for $C^\alpha$ paths with $\alpha\in(1/3,1/2)$ is is always possible to construct a rough path lift (i.e. $\int_{s<s_1<s_2<t}dX_{s_1}\otimes dX_{s_2}$) and there are other cases where we can define that iterated integral.

Comment: Consider a d dimensional data; In this case the first level of signature is collection of d real numbers ; the second level of signature is collection d^2 real numbers and so on.  So question is how do you concatenate these different levels of  signature? Do we make a long vector?

Comment: @Creator What do you mean by "concatenate"?

Comment: What we do with different levels of signatures? I assumed we need to combine them somehow?

Comment: @Creator I have no idea what that comment is supposed to mean. A signature is an object associated to a path. In the case of a rough path, some of those integrals must be postulated. The rougher the path is, the more integrals that must be postulated. Can you please clarify what you're trying to ask?

Comment: I assumed in machine learning the signatures are equivalent to features.  And therefore those features need to be arranged for comparison. I heard about 'rough path theory" 2-3 days ago and trying hard to understand, specifically how it is used in machine learning. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @Creator My academic brother is in statistics and was talking similar things, I don't know much stats/machine learning unfortunately. He was talking about algorithms to recover the iterated integrals in the case of a time series. Sounded quite neat. If you want an introduction to rough paths, check Hairer's notes. It's as easy of an introduction as you're going to get. The topic is hard.

Comment: Sure, thank you.

Comment: May I ask a question? For one dimensional case (d=1) what are the dimensions of the first few signatures ? For d dimension, I know first is 1 next is a vector of length d third is a matrix of size dxd and then it goes on 3,4 ,5 .. etc If d=1 all seems to be scalar?

Comment: @creator that's correct

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: May I ask is this question reasonable :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2775684/is-there-a-relation-between-derivative-of-a-smooth-path-and-the-signature

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to the other good answer that there are cases in which we can "compute" the integrals.

In ML applications, we usually look at paths as streams where we know the value of the path at certain times $t_1 < t_2, \ldots $ and we interpolate linearly in between.
Thanks to Chen's identity, the signature of a concatenated path is the tensor product of the signatures (if you know what it means, this identity is a homomorphism between the two spaces!). This leads to easily computable signatures.

More details can be found in Appendix A of https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.08494 or directly in the text book from Terry Lyons: Differential Equations Driven by Rough Paths (Theorem 2.9 for Chen's identity).
In the paper, they corroborate the other answer's statement:

> However one of the insights of rough path theory [10] is that a path
> needs more than just its pointwise values to be fully determined.