# Is there a relation between derivative of a smooth path and the signature?

Tags: stochastic-processes, banach-spaces, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, rough-path-theory

This question is related to rough path theory. A link to wikipedia is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_path

As I understand a signature determines a path. For this question consider a one dimensional smooth path and a corresponding signature. The question is: can there be relation between the signature obtained from the derivative of the path and the signature obtained from the original path. I understand the signature is not unique. Therefore, I am looking for a procedure or process to derive a signature so that signature from the derivative of the path can be derived from the original path/signature. Please accept my apologies if the question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g(x)$ is smooth (assuming you mean at least $C^1$), then the iterated integrals are just Stieltjes integrals and

$$\int_s^t g(r)-g(s) dg (r)=\int_s^t (g(r)-g(s)) g'(r) dr$$

No rough path theory needed, because the path is smooth, lol.

Edit: for the updated question, no there is no nice relation as far as I know. For example take any path $g$ that is $C^{1+\alpha}$ for $\alpha<1/2$. I.e. $g$ is differentiable with $C^\alpha$ derivative. Then the signature of $g$ is just iterated Stieltjes integrals, but for $g'$ you need to postulate the iterated integrals which is of course non unique.

So no, there is no nice relationship.

Comment: Does it mean the signature of the smooth path is same as the signature of the derivative of the smooth path?

Comment: @creator The two things are not remotely the same type of objects. A signature is the collection of iterated integrals. A derivative is well...a derivative lol.

Comment: I am sorry, but it seems you misunderstood. I mean if we take derivative of the path, we get another path. I am asking about the signature of that path which is obtained from derivative..

Comment: @Creator The signature of the two paths are of course not *the same* (the first term is different in each case: $g$ vs $g'$). I don't think they are related in a nice way either.

Comment: Yes, that was my question. Can we have a such relation? I am not sure the integral in your answer gives a solution to the question. I am sorry if it does, please let me know.

Comment: @Creator "The question is: can there be relation between the derivative of the path and the signature obtained from the path." it wasn't until the comments that you asked about the signature of the path vs the signature of the derivative of the path. I answered the first question, and the answer to the second question is "there is not any good relationship between the two".

Comment: @Creator Hi, you posted a video and then deleted it about the signature satisfying a differential equation. Check here: http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~friz/master4_May6th.pdf page 133, section 7.2.2. That is probably what you want